# Is there a way to assign multiple variables without writing them all manually?

Tags: python, python-3.x, variable-assignment

Is there a way to assign multiple variables without writing the code all in multiple lines one by one?

Comment: `var1, var2, var3 = 1, 2, 380`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you could try something like this:

```
a,b,c = 10,20,30
print(a,b,c)
```